# sprite sheet arrangement algorithms

Tags: performance, algorithm, sprite-sheet, zwoptex

I'm creating a simple 2d game for android using opengl and sprite-sheets, now to create these sprite-sheets I use zwoptex.

My question is, is there any utility to using any of the algorithms over any of the others,e.g. at the moment I'm using tree as it appears that very little space is wasted (though max rect also seems good).

Are there additional considerations OTHER than utilising the space efficiently to optimise graphics card performance, for example is there a cost associated between switching between 2 keyframes in an animtion if they are seperated by a large distance on the sprite-sheet or is this irrelevant due to the entire spritesheet being contained within the GPU RAM?

if there are no such possible speed benefits how exactly do the different algorithms work so I can decide which is the most efficient for what I have in mind?